# We need to read IP address one by one and then check specific location on that server

Tags: shell-script

I am having a file ip.txt which contains following details

```
cat ip.txt
10.10.100.11 10.10.100.12
10.10.100.21 10.10.100.22
10.10.100.101
10.10.100.31 10.10.100.32
10.10.100.201
eof
```

if two IP's exist on one line seperated usnig space then one may be active server and another one is passive and if only one ip then that one is Active only.

So i want script that will check the `ip.txt` file and then it will login on that active server only and get the output of `ps -ef| grep pmon`

Comment: Hi! Generally, we're not a software-development-as-a-free-service shop. We'll gladly help you with anything you're facing, though! Can you explain what you've tried so far?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please at least put some effort in trying to write the script. We can help you with scripting, but we can't be commissioned to do all the work for you, etc. Once you bump into problems while scripting, we're happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the `awk` utility to extract the first whitespace-separated field from each line of a file.

For each IP number that `awk` outputs, the shell could then use `ssh` to execute the `ps -ef` command remotely. The filtering with `grep` does not need to happen on the remote host.

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

awk '{ print $1 }' ip.txt |
while IFS= read -r remote; do
        printf 'Processing %s...\n' "$remote"
        ssh -n "$remote" ps -ef | grep -F pmon
done
```

Using the `-n` option with `ssh` stops it from reading the remaining output from `awk`, which it would otherwise do.

Using the `-F` option with `grep` causes the utility to use the given pattern for text string comparisons rather than regular expression matching. Using this option doesn't change anything for the current code, and it doesn't make it run perceivable faster (the `ssh` command will likely be the bottleneck in this script). Still, it signals to the reader that we know that we are searching with a text string rather than with a regular expression.

---

It would be reasonably easy to get rid of `awk` from this code by reading two whitespace-separated values from the input file in the loop and disregarding the second one of these.

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

while read -r remote dummy; do
        printf 'Processing %s...\n' "$remote"
        ssh -n "$remote" ps -ef | grep -F pmon
done <ip.txt
```

---

For a more permanent solution for managing a set of hosts, consider moving to something like Ansible.